# latest raspbian kernel update broke bash

Tags: boot-issues, kernel, bash, pi-3b+

I just updated by raspbian box (stretch, upgraded raspbian-kernel, using it as console only) and somehow broke bash. Every time I try to log in (either by ssh or locally) I get the following error:

> -bash: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6 ld-linux-arehf.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory.

As I've understood I'll have to reinstall raspbian (ok got another SD card prepared for that, no prob) but I'd love to have my old files from that old SD card somehow transferred to another card.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "updated by raspbian box (stretch, upgraded raspbian-kernel" mean? What did you actually do?

Answer (score 1):

To backup old files from the old SD card attach it with a card reader to a computer ideally with a debian like operating system. Look with `lsblk` what device it uses. Usually it is `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc` or something like. Mount its second partition:

```
pc ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

Now you have access to the old files:

```
pc ~$ sudo ls /mnt
```

Now you can copy your old files to where you want.